# browser version in jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

well iam trying to get version of IE used by user by using $.browser.version in IE8

iam getting different result when iam writing my url in different formats

```
http://localhost/test.html----------this is giving result=8
http://192.168.1.2/test.html--------this is giving result= 7
http://www.something.com/test.html--this is giving result= 8
```

the only problem is when iam using 192.168.1.2, this is my pc's IP , and i want url in this format for testing on network pc's.

```
i dont know why there is a difference??
```

Comment: Very strange. Are you sure that there's not an auto-switch into compatibility mode when you call 192.168.1.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the intranet sites are set to be displayed in compatibility mode.

Go to **Tools** -> **Compatibility View Settings** and unset the **Display intranet sites in compatibility view**

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 8 assumes that all Intranet applications are designed for IE7 by default. It therefore emulates IE7 for IP addresses in private ranges unless you tell it otherwise.

Add:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" >
```

for IE8 mode or

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

"Latest version" mode.

You can use a real HTTP header instead, or configure the browser preferences.

For more details, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx